# Is something wrong with this query?

Tags: php, sql

Heres the code:

```
    <?php

$post = htmlspecialchars($_GET["story"]);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("xxx", $con);


$sql="
    UPDATE `tool` SET 
        `title` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."', 
        `details` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details'])."'
    WHERE `id` = $post;";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

echo "<a href=story.php?id=";
echo $post;
echo ">Back to the story</a>";

mysql_close($con)


?>
```

So first let me describe what this is supposed to be doing.   This is supposed to be editing a post for my news system.  It has always worked, up until recently.  I have no idea what I have changed that made it stop working.  I've tried about everything I know of, changing every little details, and removing/adding parts of code.

What is happening:

When I edit a post for the FIRST time, the title, and details completely get wiped.  I have no idea why.  It only happens to each individual post, 1 time.  If I edit a second time, it stays the same, no problems at all.

Maybe if you can find no obvious flaws in my above code, then the situation I've described may help you figure out what is wrong.

I have honestly tried my best on this one, I'm not sure what is going on.  Any help is always appreciated.

Comment: There is a semicolon missing after `mysql_close($con)`

Comment: The pointless `, using htmlspecialchars for query sanitizing...

Comment: @ThiefMaster: a semicolon is not required on the last statement in a block. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: It would still be appropriate to add a semicolon.

Comment: @VincentSavard: He does use the proper function later when building the query. The only questionable thing is if html escaping should really be done before saving the data instead of after loading it.

Comment: YMMV not according to PHP Manual: "The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present."

Comment: Some of these "let's do it because we can" sort've ideas PHP implements makes me wonder. I can see leaving off the `?>` in some cases. I don't see the point of leaving off a `;` just because it's the last statement...

Comment: @ThiefMaster : As far as I see, he only uses htmlspecialchars to sanitize the variable $_GET['story'].

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I blame the syntax highlighter for not highlighting embedded variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (intval($post) > 0){
   $sql= "UPDATE `tool` SET 
                 `title` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."', 
                 `details` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details'])."'
          WHERE `id` = 'intval($post)'
          LIMIT 1";
}
```

And for the record, Parametrized query would be highly recommended for these sort of operation.

Answer (score 0):

> When I edit a post for the FIRST time, the title, and details
>   completely get wiped.

I imagine that the first time round you're not POSTing the **title** and **details** (causing `$_POST['title']` and `$_POST['details']` to be blank) whereas the second time you are.

You need to check the form that you're submitting from when these are blank. Tools such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) are perfect for this situation.

Also you really need to learn about SQL Injection and methods to guard against it.

Answer (score 0):

put the `$post` in your query between quotes:

```
WHERE `id` = '$post'
```

Comment: `$post` could be an integer, in which case it should work, so the `'` aren't required in all cases. However, there needs to be more validation and variable cleaning on the value to determine if it's what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing $_GET and $_POST.

```
$post = htmlspecialchars($_GET["story"]);
```

try

```
$post = htmlspecialchars($_POST["story"]);
```

making sure your form does post all those